# Google Sheets Function That Skips Empty Rows

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have sheets of data that goes something like this:

[image: Sample Table]

How do I make a function that pull from the `B` cells in the row similar to the `A` cells with data in them (so, in this case `B1`, `B2`, `B5`)?

Tried finding a function that would skip empty rows, but I either got errors or had the function copy empty rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pull cells from the column `B` that are in the same rows as cells with data in the column `A` in `Google Sheets`, you would use the `FILTER` function like this:

`=FILTER(B:B, A:A <> "")`